# How can I get Dataframe from Kafka using Spark Stream without json Schema?

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm a spark newbie

I'm trying to read kafka topic using Spark Stream.

The 'value' field of the data streamed from Kafka is a json string.
and I want to convert this 'value' field to a dataframe
and change it to a parquet file.

I want to get schema information from the string value contained in the value field.
cause, JSON data fields continue to be added

for example
the kafka data like this.

| key | value | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "{a:1, b:2, c:3}.." | ... |
| 1 | "{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}.." | ... |

i'm trying this code

```
   source_df = streaming_data.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").alias("value") \
         .select(from_json("value", schema_of_json(streaming_data.select('value').first().getString(0)))).alias("data") \
         .select("data.*")
```

i got error
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Hard code the schema and use it in `F.from_json()`.

```
my_schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('a', T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('b', T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('c', T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('d', T.IntegerType()),
])
value = F.col('value').cast(T.StringType())
data = F.from_json(value, my_schema).alias('data')
source_df = streaming_data.select(data).select('data.*')
```

Option 2: If you want to dynamically infer the schema, you can use [`foreachbatch`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch). But note that this is risky and breaking schema changes will fail the streaming query. Also it's not guaranteed that the schema will be inferred correctly.

```
def parse_and_process(df: DataFrame, epoch_id: int) -> None:
    # cache the current micro batch, it will be scanned more than once
    df.persist()

    # infer the schema of the current batch
    spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()

    value = F.col('value').cast(T.StringType())
    inferred_df = spark.read.json(
        df.select(value).rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]),
        dropFieldIfAllNull=True
    )
    inferred_schema = inferred_df.schema

    # parse the json with the schema
    res_df = df.withColumn('data', F.from_json(value, inferred_schema))

    # process the DataFramee, it's not a streaming DataFrame anymore.
    res_df.write....

    df.unpersist()


streaming_data.writeStream.foreachBatch(parse_and_process).start()
```

Comment: it was great help! THK!